# Receive notification when app is closed

Tags: android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver

I try to implement system to receive push notifications on my application.
I use Firebase and everything is ok when the app is active or in background but nothing happen when the app is closed.
I tried to create a `WakefullBroadcastReceiver` like that :

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String action = "com.myapp.notification.RECEIVE";
    private static final String KEY_PUSH_DATA = "com.parse.Data";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String intentAction = intent.getAction();
        switch (intentAction) {
            case action:
                String pushDataStr = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_PUSH_DATA);
                if (pushDataStr == null) {
                    return;
                }
                Log.e("PUSH", "Push data : "+pushDataStr);
                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                MyappNotificationManager.getInstance().parseBundle(extras);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

and I add this in *Manifest.xml*

```
<receiver android:name=".notification.NotificationReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.myapp.notification.RECEIVE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

It doesn't work and I can't find documentation on Android developper website.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: just a guess, but try to add these actions to your <itent-filter> tag:
<action android:name="com.myapp.notification.DELETE" />
<action android:name="com.myapp.notification.OPEN" />

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works

Comment: @Maxime is it working fine? If you don't mind paste your code here. Because I can't get any notification after app was closed. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

add to Manifest.xml :

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<application>
    <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
            <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" /> 
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

For some device models of manufacture's like Xiaomi, Redmi, Letv, Honor, Oppo, Vivo etc you need to get the `AutoStart` permission to make this work when the app is closed. And taking this permission differs from manufacturer to manufacturer where the popular Apps are already provided with AutoStart permission by the Manufacturer itself. So you could use an Android library called [AutoStarter](https://github.com/judemanutd/AutoStarter) for taking permission from such devices.