# Flutter: How can I receive local notifications even if my app is closed?

Tags: notifications, flutter

I created a Flutter app that receive signals every minute, and I display local notifications when I receive a new signal. The notifications are well displayed when the app is opened but when the app is closed, I receive nothing. I tried to add

```
    <receiver android:name=".notification.NotificationReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="io.flutter.app.notification.RECEIVE"/>
            <action android:name="io.flutter.app.notification.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="io.flutter.app.notification.OPEN" /> 
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

in my AndroidManifest.xml as shown in this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39897053/receive-notification-when-app-is-closed) for Android but it's not working.

There is a way to do that with Flutter?

Comment: You will probably need to look at Push Notifications as that works without the app running.

Answer (score 0):

If its Local notification then, try [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications), code snippet from the [sample example app](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/tree/master/example).

```
  Future<void> _showNotification() async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'your channel id', 'your channel name', 'your channel description',
        importance: Importance.Max, priority: Priority.High, ticker: 'ticker');
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
        androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0, 'plain title', 'plain body', platformChannelSpecifics,
        payload: 'item x');
  }
```

It also has the option to schedule an Notification, and route based on the Notification clicked.